# date function returns 0 when running PHP script with cron

Tags: php, cron

I have a script which builds a xml sitemap once a day using cron.

However, when run with cron the dates are all returned as 1970-01-01, so date() function must be returning 0.

If I run the script in the browser the dates are correct.

Here is my cron job.

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php73 /home/flightlist/public_html/sitemap.php
```

Here is my code.

```
function sitemap() {
$files = glob("/home/flightlist/public_html/*-cheap-one-way-flights.php");
$result = '';
foreach ($files as $file) {
$file_name = basename($file);
$file_time = date("Y-m-d", filemtime($file_name));
$result .= "<url>
<loc>https://www.flightlist.io/{$file_name}</loc>
<lastmod>{$file_time}</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
";
}
return $result;
}
$sitemap = sitemap();
$content = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'>
<url>
<loc>https://www.flightlist.io/</loc>
<lastmod>2022-03-25</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
{$sitemap}</urlset>";
file_put_contents("/home/flightlist/public_html/sitemap.xml", $content);
echo "Sitemap created!";
```

If anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong or what the issue could be it would be a great help, thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

I changed the following on the 6th line,

`$file_time = date("Y-m-d", filemtime("/home/flightlist/public_html/{$file_name}"));`

Thanks to @cOle2 for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: If I had to guess it would be your `filemtime()` call. Try changing it to the full path to the file instead of  just the filename: `filemtime($file)`. It probably works in a browser because the files exist relative to the sitemap.php script but from cron they are not in the same directory.

Comment: @cOle2 that was it, thank you. Silly mistake on my part.